# While inside another while loop with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, nested-loops

could someone give me a hint here, because I am trying to resolve the problem I have for some time, and I am getting nowhere for now.

I have one while loop which is listing all players from one team, and need to list their statistics. I tried with nested while loop, but I am not getting any results printed.

```
<?php 
while($player=mysql_fetch_array($var2)) {
    echo $player[1] ." ". $player[2] ." ". $player[3] ." ". $player[4] ." "; 
    $goal=mysql_query("SELECT A.Minute+A.Minuteadditional from Appearance A 
    where A.Type=1 and A.Appearance_ID in (Select M.ID_Matches from Matches M 
    where M.Player_ID=$player[0] and M.Match_ID=$match)",$connection);

    while($g=mysql_fetch_array($goal)) {
        echo $g[0] .", ";
    }
    echo "<br>"; 
}
?>
```

Here I tried to get all minutes when specific player scored (printed on right from his name). Query has results in phpMyadmin, but code returns no results here.

**$player[0]** is a player ID, and rest of fields are shirt number, last name, surname etc... I know that having query inside a loop is not recommended, but I am still beginner with php and this way looks to me the most logical and easier to understand.

Comment: Have you tried `echo mysql_error();` after `mysql_query()`? Also it would be a good to put only the query string in a variable and `echo` it to know what values are actually being passed.

Comment: why still using mysql instead of mysqli

Comment: You have right. There is some error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and M.Match_ID=166101)' at line 2

Comment: What's the value of `$player[0]`?

Comment: $player[0] won't work because it's in " " … use {$player[0]} instead

Comment: **This is bad PHP.** And do as @AllanStepps says. Do the same for `{$match}`.

Comment: Yes, @AllanStepps has a right. Now it is working. And I know it is bad PHP. I am still a novice in this... :/

Comment: If you have a chance, take a look at `PHP: PDO`. Your code will be more readable and reliable. http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php

Comment: @Naeem, I know for that. It is scheduled for an implementation, but later...

Comment: @darkoKc Always put `$variables` in a `"string"` like this: `"this is a {$variable} and an {$array['index']} in a string"`. They must be wrapped in curly brackets.

Comment: This is bad mysql too!

Comment: @AllanStepps, I will. Thank you for your comments. Thanks to others too.

Comment: @CodeAngry, thanks for advice. I still have a lot to learn about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you using

```
$player[1] ." ". $player[2] ." ". $player[3] ." ". $player[4]
```

then i guess you should use `mysql_fetch_row` instead.

then your code will be

```
 while($player=mysql_fetch_row($var2)) {
```

Try this

```
<?php 
 $player=mysql_fetch_row($var2);

 $goal=mysql_query("SELECT A.Minute+A.Minuteadditional from Appearance A 
 where A.Type=1 and A.Appearance_ID in (Select M.ID_Matches from Matches M 
 where M.Player_ID = $player[0] and M.Match_ID = $match)",$connection);

 while($g=mysql_fetch_row($goal)) {
echo $g[0] .", ";
}

?>
```

Comment: I need to skip $player[0], and some other columns, e.g. $player[5], are used for other purposes (if statement) which is not shown here. I simplified code, for the question purpose.

Comment: dont understand what you want do.

Comment: sorry, I was thinking about something else. You have right. I change the code as you advised. Thanks.

Comment: @darkoKc you welcome ! make sure to accept answer as solved to the left.